# Функция include/require не работает вообще

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Я по работе разбираюсь с сайтом, который писал не я. И я никак не могу его запустить... я получаю пустую страницу что бы я не делал! Я сумел локализировать ошибку ровно до этого момента:

```
<?php
final class Template {

    public function view($file, $params = array())
    {
            //Не представляю зачем это надо
        $newTplClass = new Template();
        $this->tpl = $newTplClass;

        // Установка переменных для шаблона.
        foreach ($params as $k => $v)
        {
            $$k = $v;
        }

        // Генерация HTML в строку.
        ob_start();

        $path = DIR_APPLICATION . 'views/' . $file;

        echo $path;   //это - выводится.

        require_once $path;    //Здесь просто пропасть

        echo 'Это не выводится!';

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
?>
```

строка с `require_once` просто проглатывается компилятором и выполнение прекращается! Более того, какой-бы параметр я не передал в `require_once` она не выводит ни ошибок ни предупреждений. Однако, если поместить её в начало файла, до класса `template`, эта функция работает как надо. Я весь день бьюсь над этой проблемой и не сдвинулся ни на йоту! Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Внутри класса нельзя делать `include` / `require`. Если `PHP`>=5.4 почитайте про [трейты](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php), но это для ООП, если вам нужно просто HTML, то тут нужно логику получения HTML как-то изменить.

чуть не в тему, но может будет полезно касательно ["установка переменных для шаблона"](https://www.php.net/extract)

Comment: Мм, но до меня же все работало) почти сразу как написал вопрос понял в чем дело.. внутри включаемого файла были старомодные теги <? ?>, которые почему-то приводили к такой тихой ошибке... Может бчть есть способ включить вывод ворнинга когда компилятор находит такие тэги?

Comment: Ну это довольно спорное утверждение, так как сам подключанию шаблоны страницы прямо внутри класса, а затем в шаблоне вывожу переменные как-нибудб типа так:

    <title><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></title>

Довольно удобно в некоторых случаях:))

Comment: Может я что-то не так понял, сейчас вряд ли найду где я вычитал, что нельзя так делать. Возможно там было что не рекомендуется, а не нельзя. Но вот в голову запало именно что нельзя так делать.

Comment: ps: в magento примерно так и инклудится.